# Custom PMD Rule - Check Package Comment In Place

Tags: java, static-analysis, pmd

I'm trying to write a rule to enforce that a package contains a Javadoc comment with a particular expression, e.g:

```
/**
 * Example Expression
 */
```

Does anybody know how I would write such a rule using the **AbstractJavaRule** class.  I've looked at ASTPackageDeclaration, but this doesn't appear to have what I want.

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PMD uses JavaCC to parse each java file into an Abstract Syntax Tree.  Typically parsers used for compilation just drop comments, and from what I can gather on the ["How to write a rule"](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtowritearule.html) page, PMD is also dropping comments from the AST.

But looking at the PMD forum, it does look like [comments are preserved as a SPECIAL_TOKEN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/forums/forum/188192/topic/2134288), but it is difficult to align them with the AST node they are associated with.  So you may have a hard time writing this rule.  Have you looked at [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) instead?  It has a [RegexpHeader rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_header.html#RegexpHeader) that may do what you want.

Comment: Great response, thanks.  I'll take a look today and see if I can get the comments with PMD.  I saw in the Design Rules section there's a check for UncommentedEmptyMethod.  Looks promosing, failing that I'll drop to Checkstyle and try that.