# pmd rule for checking java code for comments

Tags: java, myeclipse, pmd

i need a PMD java class for checking comments on java code. I am working on MyEclipse IDE. any idea?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166661/custom-pmd-rule-check-package-comment-in-place for a similar question (not on the exact same kind of comment though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a PMD rule, you can use the internal compiler to raise missing documentation as warning (or even error).

Look under Eclipse preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> JavaDoc

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just want to develop that functionality in PMD plugin.