# need java pmd rule for comments in myeclipse

Tags: java, pmd

i am trying to write a java pmd rule to check source code comments. The rule should be able to identify all the method and variable declarations. If any method/variable declares without comment, the rule should give a warning as method/variable created without comments. any idea will be appreciated.......!

Comment: duplicate of your former question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965937/pmd-rule-for-checking-java-code-for-comments

Comment: yes it was..! sorry for that. But i didnt get exact solution even i go though d specified link. Cant v implement java rule for comments? Is there any pmd RegexHeader rule like in checkstyle?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible with PMD because XPath expressions are working on the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and AST does not contain comments. Maybe Checkstyle would be a better candidate for this task.

(You can check this with a PMD plugin in Eclipse. Right click on a class which contains some comments, PMD / Generate Abstract Syntax Tree, then search in the generated ast file for your comments. There is no sign of any of them.)